# DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND alternative in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

```
DECLARE c_cursor CURSOR FOR  
       SELECT column_name FROM tablename WHERE column_name1 = 0 AND column_name2 = value ;
BEGIN
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND v_variable1 = 1;
        v_variable2 = 1;
        OPEN c_cursor;
        get_email: 
        LOOP
          FETCH c_cursor INTO v_variable3;
          IF v_variable1 = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE get_email;
          END IF; 
          UPDATE table_name SET column_name1 = v_variable2 WHERE column_name2 = v_variable3;
          v_variable2 := v_variable2 + 1;
        END LOOP get_email;
 CLOSE c_cursor;
```

How to convert above mysql code into postgresql.
What is alternative of declare handler not found.

Comment: For those that don't know MySQL: what does this "handler" do? My guess is: you want an [exception handler](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING)

Comment: And I don't think you need a cursor to begin

Comment: Yes it is exception handler in my sql but how to migrate above code into postgresql

Comment: Did you read the link I provided? It explains how to catch exceptions. But as I said: I am pretty sure you don't need a loop or PL/pgSQL at all. This can be done with a simple UPDATE statement (although your obfuscated table and column names make it **really** hard to understand what you are doing there)

Comment: I think something like this: http://dpaste.com/3404F1Y is what you really want

Answer (score 1):

With PostgreSQL procedural language (plpgsql), you can test `FOUND` directly after a `FETCH` without the need for a specific handler that transfers this state into a custom variable (which is apparently the way it's done with MySQL).

So the specific change would be:

```
 FETCH c_cursor INTO v_variable3;
 IF NOT FOUND  THEN
   ...
```

[Doc quote](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS):

> The second method to determine the effects of a command is to check
>   the special variable named FOUND, which is of type boolean. FOUND
>   starts out false within each PL/pgSQL function call. It is set by each
>   of the following types of statements:
>
> A SELECT INTO statement sets FOUND true if a row is assigned, false if no row is returned.
>
> A PERFORM statement sets FOUND true if it produces (and discards) one or more rows, false if no row is produced.
>
> UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements set FOUND true if at least one row is affected, false if no row is affected.
>
> **A FETCH statement sets FOUND true if it returns a row, false if no row is returned.**
>
> A MOVE statement sets FOUND true if it successfully repositions the cursor, false otherwise.
>   [...]